# How to convert Apache rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

```
<LocationMatch "^/(starwars|ironman|hulk|blackwidow|thor|loki)($|/|\?)">
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
        RewriteRule "^(.+)" "https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}" [P]
</Locationmatch>
```

This is my apache rewrite rule, I tried a couple of options as suggested in google. But that didnt work for me. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use if condition in nginx (though it is not suggested) and it worked for me.

```
location ~* ^/(starwars|ironman|hulk|blackwidow|thor|loki)($|/|\?)>
    root /location/of/files/;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    }
```